Universal unitary matrix (logic gate) that amplify imaginary part and nullify real part, and vice versa
Let $ U_{fj} $ unitary matrix that amplify imaginary part:
For example:

$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 + 0.707j \\ 0.707 + 0j \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 + 1j \\ 0 + 0j \end{pmatrix} $
$ \begin{pmatrix} 0.707 + 0j \\ 0 + 0.707j \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 + 0j \\ 0 + 1j \end{pmatrix} $
$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 + 0.707j \\ 0 + 0.707j \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0 + 0.707j \\ 0 + 0.707j \end{pmatrix} $
Else, keep real part

$ \begin{pmatrix} 0.707 + 0j \\ 0.707 + 0j \end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix} 0.707 + 0j \\ 0.707 + 0j \end{pmatrix} $
Basically, I want to measure imaginary part or real part. I just realized that one qubit is basically list of complex number with two elements, and complex number basically vector with two elements (real part and imaginary part). Hence, one qubit contains 4 classical states at a moment.
If real part treated as variabel A, and imaginary part variabel B. Then there is relationship between this table:



var_a(real)
var_b(imag)
statevec (1-qubit)




0
0
[ 0.707+0.707j, 0+0j ]


0
1
[ 0.707+0j, 0+0.707j ]


1
0
[ 0+0.707j, 0.707+0j ]


1
1
[ 0+0j, 0.707+0.707j ]



Suppose there is arbitrary state vector with unknown state. I want to measure its imaginary part, if it's containing real part then the real value must be absorbed into imaginary part equally so when it's measured, I can see clearly the imaginary part (in this case I'm measuring variabel B).
So, how to measure imaginary part in an unknown statevector of a qubit? Will the unitary matrix is irreversible? I mean when performed again, it's undoing into previous state (back to the "before amplification").

This transformation your describing sounds highly non-linear and non unitary. It also would depend on the global phase of the system which shouldn't make a difference to the computation but here it would make all the difference to what the output of the state is.

@EthanDavies What is the closest solution about how the measurement focuses on imaginary part only somehow?

This issue is if we run your process U on |psi>, it should achieve the same measurement results if you run U on e^ix |psi>, where you have now changed what the phases of all the coefficients are. I don't think such a U would exist in any meaningful way.

Your intended unitary has a couple of significant problems. The first is that unitaries preserve the length of vectors. Your transformation clearly doesn't preserve the length.
Secondly is the issue of global phase. You want
$$
(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}\rightarrow|1\rangle
$$
and you want
$$
(-i|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}\rightarrow |0\rangle.
$$
However, these two inputs are the same up to a global phase. There is no way to detect a global phase, so the behaviour of both of those inputs has to be the same, which it clearly isn't. Unless you resolve this ambiguity, there's not enough of a concept to talk meaningfully about some sort of "closest" operation.

Since there is no way to detect global phase, what if I'm using one ancilla qubit as the phase reference? So, it will be relative phase towards a qubit that needs to measure?

It's not immediately obvious to me how that would help...

I have no idea too, just my intuition said that. Perhaps controlled gate can be helpful.
